# Flutter/ Dart: Add items from list to JSON body

Tags: json, flutter, dart, http-post

I have a situation: I need to push images to Airtable using their Rest API (from my flutter app) like this:

```
POST https://api.airtable.com/v0/<base>/<table name> \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{
  "fields": {
    "Pictures": [
      {
        "url": "imageUrl1"
      },
      {
        "url": "imageUrl2"
      }
    ],
    "Variation": "Original"
  }
}'
```

I have a list of urls which is generated after uploading images to cloud storage and it looks like this:

```
imageURL = [imageUrl1, imageUrl2, imageUrl3, ... ]
```

I need help inserting the urls from list to json body.

I was able to do this by converting the list to map like: `{url: imageUrl}`, but the output always gives me a map with length 1.

I am sure there's a simple solution to this, but I am unable to figure it out. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have something like:

```
var imageURL = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4'];
```

and you do something like:

```
 var mapped = imageURL.map((url) => { 'url': url }).toList();
```

Then the output would look like:

```
[{url: url1}, {url: url2}, {url: url3}, {url: url4}]
```

Is that what you're looking for to do?

Comment: There you go.. That's the one. It worked! I wasted 6 hours trying to figure this one out. Awesome. Worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

try this get the list and do .map

//Body to pass

```
final data = {
     "fields": {
        "Pictures": imageURL.map((e)=> 
           {
             // e is the data which the imageUrl1 and so fort
             "url": e
           }
             ).toList(),
         "Variation": "Original"
    }

};
```